# How to format textboxes in MDI child form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an application
that has several MDI child forms and a parent form.

I want to add a format button in the parent form's menu toolstrip, so
when clicking on the Format button the following changes should be applied:

Focus on the Textbox of the active form.

Please have you any idea how to do this?

Comment: What decides what the active child form is?

Comment: sir there are 12 child forms
out of them every 4 has the same number and name of textboxes

Comment: You are saying when you click the format button the textbox on the active child form should get focused right? Which one is the active child form? Or is there always only one child form open?

Comment: No sir i mean there is a button Bold
so when i will click on it then
it should bold the text of:
Active Child form Focused Textbox Only not all textboxes.
just focused textbox text of active child form should be change to Bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void btnFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
        {
            Form testform = ActiveMdiChild;
            Control cont = testform.ActiveControl;
            if (cont is TextBox)
            {
                //((TextBox)cont).Text = "Nasir Khan";
                FontDialog fontDialog1 = new FontDialog();
                // Show the dialog.
                DialogResult result = fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
                // See if OK was pressed.
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // Get Font.
                    Font font = fontDialog1.Font;
                    ((TextBox)cont).Font = font;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```